# Can't Use Tab in Python Shell

Tags: python, python-3.4

Using tab in Python 3.4, I get the following message:

```
Display all 184 possibilites? (y or n)
```

Is there a way to allow tabbing in Python 3.4?

Comment: You're seeing the use of tab-complete, which is incredibly helpful (usually). Try doing `import sys; sys.` then hit tab, and you'll see all the autocomplete options underneath `sys.`. You could (and should IMO) use spaces instead of tabs for indentation, then get best of both worlds.

Comment: @JoshSmeaton If you're scripting in the terminal, using tab is much faster than using spaces (and more reliable). I'd hate to count out 12 spaces for an if statement inside a method inside a class.

Comment: the new recommendation is use spaces, but single spaces don't separate blocks enough, and 4 spaces is too laborious to type out.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a change introduced in the development versions of Python 3.4.  It has been somewhat controversial.  You might want to voice your opinions [on the issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue5845).

Answer (score 11):

Instead of tabbing you can use spaces. And in the interactive interpreter, you don't have to type out 4 spaces. Here I'm using two spaces to minimize the number of keystrokes.

```
if 1 == 1:
  print('Hello Kitty')
  print('Oh no, only two spaces for a new block')
```

To disable `tab: complete`, you can do the following.

Create or edit a file on your home directory called `.pythonrc`
In the file add the following lines and save

```
import readline  
readline.parse_and_bind("set disable-completion on")  
readline.parse_and_bind("tab: self-insert")
```

Edit your `~/.bashrc` file and add the following line

```
export PYTHONSTARTUP=$HOME/.pythonrc
```

Start the `python3` interpreter. `Tab` should work like it used to.

Or, you can bind complete to another key instead of tab, and you would get the proverbial best of both worlds.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Got my tab indentation back!

Answer (score 2):

To edit this behavior out without having to set environment variables for your whole account, you can do the initialization in `~/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/usercustomize.py`. As @HaleemurAli wrote, the code to disable tab-completion is:

```
import readline  
readline.parse_and_bind("set disable-completion on")  
readline.parse_and_bind("tab: self-insert")
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be fixed (reverted) in more recent versions of 3.4 and 3.5, and presumably all future versions for the foreseeable future.

http://bugs.python.org/issue23441#msg247482

Answer (score 0):

So how do I do that in windows? This is a big pain in the neck.

Actually, the simple solution was to get the excellent free autohotkey keyboard programmer, and put this in the .ahk file ;')

Tab::
Send {Space}{Space}{Space}{Space}

(Your editor doesn't show the fact that Send *** is on the second line.)